# How to upgrade Debian 10.5 to 10.6?

Tags: debian

I'm unsure if minor release upgrades like 10.5 to 10.6 are simply achieved just by doing `apt update && apt full-upgrade -y`. I can't find anything on web to confirm this.

`lsb_release -a` doesn't give me any further information about this.

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they do. You don't need anything more than these commands.

You can type `cat /etc/debian_version` to check Debian minor version.

Comment: Strange, it shows `10.7` although only 10.6 is released (at the time of writing this)

Comment: 10.7 was released today (5th Dec)  https://www.debian.org/News/2020/20201205

Comment: impeccable timing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `lsb-release` package is [buggy](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=939733), you can use the stretch version (no dependency problem) to print the Point Release:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/lsb/lsb-release_9.20161125_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i lsb-release_9.20161125_all.deb
sudo apt-mark hold lsb-release
lsb_release -a
```

Comment: It is never a good idea to go back to old software. Also, the real issue is no in the `lsb-release` package but in `base-files`.